# T-SQL Case in Where issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried to search trough several bolgs however,I am still struggling with the issue in SQL case in Where Clause. Could someone please help me out? Below is the scenario-

I have a table Client_Master, I have to create a stored proc to display:

1. All companies from all clients when user clicks on All radio button
2. All companies specific to Only Client1 when user clicks on Client1 radio Button
3. All companies specific to Only Client2 when user clicks on Client2 radio Button

I tried writing SQL code as -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ClientSearchList
--Exec ClientSearchList
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
BEGIN
Declare @Filter Varchar(10)
Set @Filter = Null
SELECT DISTINCT client_Name FROM M_CLIENT_MASTER
Where case 
WHEN @Filter = 'ALL' THEN Client_id <> 0 AND Activate = 0
WHEN @Filter = 'TATA' THEN Client_id <> 0 and Activate = 0 and (Client_Name like '%Tata%' OR   Client_Type=9)
WHEN @Filter = 'CONCEPT' THEN

IF @@ERROR <> 0 GOTO ERRORHANDLER**
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    RETURN(0)

ERRORHANDLER:
    RETURN(@@ERROR)
END
```

Please suggest a way to get this working.

Thanks,
Vidya

Comment: You set @Filter to null and then test it for values. The tests can not be evaluated to true.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why people new to SQL seem to reach for `CASE`<sup>1</sup> when all they need are boolean operators - the same type of operators they surely use in other languages:

```
Where
   (@Filter = 'ALL' AND Client_id <> 0 AND Activate = 0) OR
   (@Filter = 'TATA' AND Client_id <> 0 and Activate = 0 and
        (Client_Name like '%Tata%' OR Client_Type=9)) OR
   (@Filter = 'CONCEPT' AND ... )
```

Question leaves `CONCEPT` branch incomplete, so answer does too. Also, those first two branches look to have some similarities, so could be simplified:

```
Where
   (Client_id <> 0 AND Activate = 0 AND
       (@Filter = 'ALL' OR
           (@Filter = 'TATA' AND
               (Client_Name like '%Tata%' OR Client_Type=9)
           )
       )
   ) OR
   (@Filter = 'CONCEPT' AND ... )
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `CASE` is an *expression* - it computes a single *value*. It's not some form of control flow. There aren't any such control flow constructs for use *within* a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Hi Damien, Thanks for your suggestions. However, what I was looking for when I select All, my proc should have 2 things in where for that which is (Client_id <> 0 AND Activate = 0) but when I select Tata, Where should have (Client_id <> 0 AND Activate = 0 and (Client_Name like '%Tata%' OR Client_Type=9)). I didn't mention conditions for Concept as it is similar to Tata. So kinldy ignore that case. Thanks

Comment: @VidyaNandTiwari - That is, effectively, what my answer shows.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried building query using IF and everything worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can work for u

```
Select 
ProductID
OrderNo,
OrderType,
OrderLineNo
From Order_Detail
Where ProductID in (
Select Case when (@Varibale1 != '') 
then (Select ProductID from Product P Where .......)
Else (Select ProductID from Product)
End as ProductID
)
```

Comment: can you add an explanation of what this change is and why it would work? It's a bit hard to figure out from the example.